# Add extra arguments to a call to super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In `as_json` you can add `methods` return values to get included in the json.  In this example I want to always have it return *name* and *title* as well.

But the way I'm doing it now, it will overwrite the methods passed in as options from the user.

```
def as_json(options)
  options.merge!({methods: [:name, :title]})

  super(options)
end
```

I was wondering if there is a way to call super with the users options in addition to my own.

Comment: In what respect is the approach you posted not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think simple conditional will do the trick if I get you correctly.

```rb
def as_json(options)
  if options[:methods].empty? || options[:methods].nil?
    options.merge!({methods: [:name, :title]})
  else
    options[:methods] << [:name, :title]
  end

  super(options)
end
```

You can also add elsif `is_a?(Array)` before pushing but it depends what your options structure is.

Comment: `Hash#merge` accepts a block to handle this i.e. `options.merge!({methods: [:name, :title]}) {|_,old,new| new.concat([*old]).compact.uniq}` can replace your conditional. Also worth mentioning the signature should be `as_json(options={})` since `to_json` is often called without args